# Java Reflection Object Instantiation

Tags: java, object, reflection, instantiation

I want to call at runtime a method that consists of both objects and primitive parameters ( e.g. `doAction(User username, BankAccount ba, int value )`). Assuming that the User object is composed of other objects (e.g. each `User` has an `Address` and a `FullName`) is there any framework / library to assist me with the object instantiation, without having to recursively walk the 'tree of objects' and instantiate all of them ( start with `FullName`, then `Address` and then move to `User`) ?

Thank you

Comment: Is it right that you want to call doAction with dummy values? Then why not using `null`? Or do you want to deserialize the arguments (objects and primitives) from some file/string value?

Comment: AFAIK no.  But if you are concerned about the amount of code you need to write, then the simpler way to instantiate objects and call methods is *without* using reflection in the first place.